# How to extract attachments data in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, soql, lightning-experience, attachment

I'm currently using the Document object/table in SOQL to extract attachments in Salesforce classic.

As far as I'm aware in Lightning it is necessary to use File instead of Document object to extract attachments.

In SOQL there is no such File table and I need to know how to extract attachments data in Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get list of all files you can query **ContentDocument** object

```sql
SELECT Id, Title, ContentAssetId FROM ContentDocument
```

2. If the ContentDocument is an asset file, this field points to the asset. For most entities, the value of this field is null.
   You can query extract data using the following query (even assets):

```sql
SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :myContentDocumentId AND IsLatest = true
```

You can read more about that here: [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) and [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm).

If you need to get files that are attached to a specific record, you'd need to first query against [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) and filter upon LinkedEntityId with the recordId to get ContentDocumentIds.
Example:

```sql
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId
FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It's correct for exporting attachments in Lightning Experience; you must select File instead.

```
SELECT FileExtension, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE (ContentDocumentId = '<ContentDocumentId>' or Id='<ContentVersionId>') and IsLatest=true
```

Or if you want an easy way to download all Files from Stand or Custom object, then you can Try AppExchange App Satrang Mass File Download. This app works in both Expernice Lightning and Classic, and in just a few clients, users can download the bulk of files Attchmnets Documents - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e.

*Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologie, the publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.*

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation to the link!